# Agent is picked even if stage is disabled from when expresion

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I need some help with the following scenario. I'm starting a Jenkins pipeline through the main agent . My pipeline is structured in stages. The first 2 stages are assigned to the main agent (more exactly, I'm not declaring another agent). The 3rd stage, called Polyspace in my case, contains the node{} structure.The purpose of this is to use another agent to perform this stage.

The problem being faced is the following:

When I disable the parameter for the 'Polyspace' stage (parameter set to 'false'), the Polyspace agent is being selected for checkout (I'm using git as SCM). I want, if it is possible not to select the agent, when the expression in that stage is set to false. The reason behind this, is due to only having 1 node agent that can perform a "Polyspace" step within a big Continuous Integration system (all the pipelines). So, if this agent is selected, even when the "Polyspace" stage is disabled, the pipeline will be required to wait until the agent is available. (I have just 1 executor).

Info:
XXX_1 -> The Jenkins main agent for stages 'Init' & 'Compile', are by default assigned to the 'main' agent.

YYY_1 ->  The 'in-demand' agent for 'Polyspace' stage
You can see within the parameters block that the parameter "POLYSPACE" is set to 'false' by default, so the stage will be skipped due to the 'when' condition block.

My Pipeline:

```
@Library('SLXXX') _

log.init("info")

pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label 'XXX_1'
        }
    }
    triggers {
        cron('H 1 * * *')
    }
    options {
        disableConcurrentBuilds()
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '10'))
        timeout(time: 4, unit: 'HOURS')
        timestamps ()
    }
    
    parameters {
        booleanParam(name: 'INIT', defaultValue: true, description: 'Init after yaml script update')
        booleanParam(name: 'COMPILE', defaultValue: true, description: 'Run COMPILE')
        booleanParam(name: 'POLYSPACE', defaultValue: false, description: 'Run polyspace')

        
    }
    
    stages {
        stage('Init') {
            when { expression { params.INIT } }
            steps {
                script {
                    xxx
                }
                script {
                    xxx
                }
            }
        }
    
        stage('Compile') {
            when { expression { params.COMPILE } }
            steps {
                dir('ThirdParty/Jenkins') {
                    xxx
                }
                
                archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'xxx'
                archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'xxx'
                archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'xxx'
            }
        }
        stage('Polyspace') {
            agent {
                node {
                    label 'YYY_1'
                }
            }
            when { expression { params.POLYSPACE } }
                options {
                    timeout(time: 3, unit: 'HOURS') 
                }
            steps {
                script {
                    // run polyspace build from yaml file description
                        mqPipelineConfigPolyspace(config)
                }
            }
        }   

    }
    
        
    post { 
        always { 
            echo 'This will always run for saving artifacts from failed tests'
        }
        
        success {
            echo 'This will run only if successful'
            script
                {
                xxx
                }
        }
        failure {
            echo 'This will run only if failed'
            script
                {
                xxx
                }
        }
    }

}
```

I want to disable POLYSPACE parameter and agent selection should be ignored. Everything from that stage should be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `beforeAgent` directive within your `when` condition block, before the `agent` block. Move the `when` block to be evaluated before the agent is selected.

By default, the when condition for a stage will be evaluated after entering the agent for that stage, if one is defined. However, this can be changed by specifying the beforeAgent option within the when block. If beforeAgent is set to true, the when condition will be evaluated first, and the agent will only be entered if the when condition evaluates to true. [Jenkins User Handbook - Pipeline Syntax - Evaluating when before entering agent in a stage](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#evaluating-when-before-entering-agent-in-a-stage)

The directive `beforeAgent true` being placed in the `when` block will be evaluated first before deciding any action with an agent. Thus, if the parameter value is set to false, then the stage will `skip due to conditional`, which will avoid selecting / waiting for / spinning up the declared agent to run the conditional/stage.

Update your jenkinsfile 'Polyspace' stage to the following:

```
stage('Polyspace') {
            when { 
              expression { params.POLYSPACE.toBoolean() } 
              beforeAgent true
              }
            agent {
                node {
                    label 'YYY_1'
                }
            }
                options {
                    timeout(time: 3, unit: 'HOURS') 
                }
            steps {
                script {
                    // run polyspace build from yaml file description
                        mqPipelineConfigPolyspace(config)
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: @MihaiToma - Based on your confirmation, can you appropriately show the answer as upvoted / accepted